# Pentaho - Transformation is killing the other steps

Tags: pentaho, transformation

For Pentaho ETL, I am getting below detailed error in one environment :

```
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - TRF_STAGING_FCT_LOAD_ACTUAL_SALES - Dispatching started for transformation [TRF_STAGING_FCT_LOAD_ACTUAL_SALES]
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Get transformation and job batch ID.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Set var_etl_trf_id_batch and var_etl_job_id_job.0 - Setting environment variables...
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Set var_etl_trf_id_batch and var_etl_job_id_job.0 - Set variable VAR_ETL_TRF_ID_BATCH to value [819960]
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Set var_etl_trf_id_batch and var_etl_job_id_job.0 - Set variable VAR_ETL_JOB_ID_JOB to value [62962]
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Set var_etl_trf_id_batch and var_etl_job_id_job.0 - Finished after 1 rows.
2015/11/16 15:46:07 - Set var_etl_trf_id_batch and var_etl_job_id_job.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : !Calculator.ErrorInStepRunning : 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [flag_SALES_WEEK Integer] to an Integer
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - !
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Error while running the step 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [flag_SALES_WEEK Integer] to an Integer
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.calculator.Calculator.processRow(Calculator.java:178)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException: 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [flag_SALES_WEEK Integer] to an Integer
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - 
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getInteger(ValueMetaBase.java:1815)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.ValueDataUtil.plus(ValueDataUtil.java:412)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.calculator.Calculator.calcFields(Calculator.java:253)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.calculator.Calculator.processRow(Calculator.java:162)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  ... 2 more
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getInteger(ValueMetaBase.java:1736)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 -  ... 5 more
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Calculate number of truncated fields for row.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=286, W=285, U=0, E=1)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Flag_truncated_fields.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=328, W=328, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Set Var fields truncated 2.0 - We didn't receive a row while setting the default values.
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Remove leading zeros from material.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1104, W=1104, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Filter rows.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=285, W=285, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Select values 5 2.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=364, W=364, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Strings cut.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=368, W=736, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:22 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2015/11/16 15:46:23 - No fields truncated for row.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=285, W=285, U=0, E=0)
2015/11/16 15:46:23 - Set Var fields truncated 2.0 - Finished after 0 rows.
2015/11/16 15:46:23 - Transformation is killing the other steps!

STOP
```

But on production I am getting only 4 lines for same excel file:

```
2015/11/16 13:40:23 - TRF_STAGING_FCT_LOAD_ACTUAL_SALES - Dispatching started for transformation [TRF_STAGING_FCT_LOAD_ACTUAL_SALES]
2015/11/16 13:40:25 - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2015/11/16 13:40:25 - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2015/11/16 13:40:25 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Errors detected!

STOP
```

Does anyone have any clue why the detailed error has been lost in the error?

Comment: theres an error comes from one of the steps so it starts killing the execution of other steps. If you attach the ktr with sample data we can help find the issue

Comment: Hi, On Development environment I can get detailed error. Only on production, I have problem. Somehow the detailed error message is getting surpressed and hence not getting captured in log file.